# Define additional math operators to be typeset in roman

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

Mathematical operators, such as function names, should be set in roman type, not italics. Latex already has commands for some operators, including `\max`, `\min`, and `\log`.  How can I define additional such commands?

Answer (score 161, accepted):

`\DeclareMathOperator{\foo}{foo}` and `\DeclareMathOperator*{\hocolim}{hocolim}` for sub- and superscripts in the limits position.

This requires

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

which is recommended for math documents anyway.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\foo}{foo}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\hocolim}{hocolim}

\begin{document}

Example of $\foo(x)$ and $\foo x$.

Example of $\hocolim_{x\in X} f(x)$ and displayed
\begin{equation*}
\hocolim_{x\in X} f(x)
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great!  I thought there was some way of handling the limits, but couldn't remember it.

Comment: Could someone clarify the one for sub/super-scripts?  Would `hocolim` take sub/super-scripts, or would it appear in them?

Comment: Both `\foo` and `\hocolim` can take sub/superscripts, the difference is in how the subscripts and superscripts appear in display mode. The sub/superscripts to an operator defined with `\DeclareMathOperator` will always be placed after foo, while sub/superscripts to operators defined with `\DeclareMathOperator*` will be placed above and below the function name in display mode.

Answer (score 51):

As mentioned before, the amsmath command `\DeclareMathOperator{\Det}{Det}` is a good way to do this, but this is actually basically a wrapper for `\newcommand{\Det}{\operatorname{Det}}`.  So if you only want to use the command once and don't want to define a symbol (especially useful if you are using an online tex editor), then just use `\operatorname`

And just like `\DeclareMathOperator*`, you can use `\operatorname*` to specify that underbraces should go underneath.  This is useful for something like 
`\operatorname*{minimize}`. More info [here](http://www.latex-community.org/know-how/latex/51-latex-math-science/207-defining-operators-like-sin-log-etc)

Answer (score 38):

Alternatively, if you are using any of the packages from the AMS (`amsart.cls` or `amsmath.sty`) then there is a command `\DeclareMathOperator` which does what it says on the tin!  For example,

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\Det}{Det}
```

I think that it can handle variants, but I don't recall off the top of my head.

Comment: Ah, you were faster :-)

Answer (score 14):

If you're looking for something one-off, you can always use `\mathrm` in a math environment like so:

```
\mathrm{ultimatefunction}(x)
```

Which will display 'ultimatefunction' in a roman type.

[image]

Comment: Note that `\mathrm` differs from `\operatorname` or `\DeclareMathOperator` in terms of spacing, and that the latter two are preferable to the first in this respect (see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48463/13034) for more detailed information).

Comment: I ended up using `\operatorname` as mentioned by @AndrewUzzell, but I just wanted to point out that `\mathrm` and `\operatorname` are great for those working with the limited LaTeX subset available in Apple's Keynote equation editor.

Answer (score 5):

Define the command \newoperator as follows:

```
\providecommand{\newoperator}[3]{%
  \newcommand*{#1}{\mathop{#2}#3}}
```

Here is an example that defines \FD as an operator:

```
\newoperator{\FD}{\mathrm{FD}}{\nolimits}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you need use this new operator only one time, maybe you could considere use

```
\text{operator}
```

in the math formula.

```
For example:  $$ 3 \cdot \text{FoO} (x) $$
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or hit Ctrl+K. You may want to have a look to [Why is \[ … \] preferable to $$ … $$?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/13304) to better typeset equations.

Comment: this won't always set the specified string in roman type; if it's within an italicized theorem environment, it will come out in italics.  also, it won't accommodate limits correctly, if such are needed, and the spacing won't be quite the same as for a "real" operator.

Comment: Thank you, @Claudio Fiandrino. I'm reading your link now.

Answer (score 4):

A one-off operator that you don’t think is worth defining a new macro for can be typeset with `\operatorname`.  It uses the same font as `\mathrm`, which by default is the main text font.  However, `unicode-math` also defines a command `\setoperatorfont` to change this.  (In LaTeX, it is possible to redefine `\operator@font`.)  Additionally, `fontspec` allows you to `\setmathrm`.

```
\( \operatorname{foo}_a^b f \equiv
   \int_a^b \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \,\mathrm{d}y \,\mathrm{d}x
\)
```

[image: Sample using \operatorname]

This also requires `amsmath`.