# Definition of cotan function

Tags: math-operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Define additional math operators to be typeset in roman](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/671/define-additional-math-operators-to-be-typeset-in-roman)

Is the cotan function defined somewhere? I cannot find it. It is defined as cotan(x)=cos(x)/sin(x). Should it be `\newcommand{\cotan}{\mathrm{cotan}}`? I'm suspecting somewhere a `declareoperator` command or something.

Comment: For a function to _calculate_ cotan=cos/sin, `\usepackage{fp}`... `;-)`

Answer (score 0):

Check the `amsopn.sty` file.

and define the the tag

```
\def\cotan{\qopname\relax o{cotan}}
```

Comment: Easier to use `\DeclareMathOparator`, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/671/define-additional-math-operators-to-be-typeset-in-roman

Comment: NB: you can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) and if you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "101010" on it).