# Create a new integral symbol

Tags: math-mode, symbols

Is it possible without creating a new font to define a new math symbol (e.g. with `\newcommand`) and then use it with such commands as `\limits`, `_` and `^` (up and down limits)?

For example, I define it like this:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\bigrint}{\scalebox{1.2}[1] {\rotatebox[origin=c]{15}{$\displaystyle\int$}}}
\newcommand{\rint}[2]{ \substack{\hspace{-4pt} #2 \\ \hspace{-5pt} \bigrint \hspace{-3pt}\\ #1}\hspace{-1pt} }
```

And I want to use it like `\rint_1^2`.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/671/define-additional-math-operators-to-be-typeset-in-roman

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23432/how-to-create-my-own-math-operator-with-limits

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath}
\newcommand{\bigrint}{%
  \hbox to .2em{\hss\scalebox{1.2}[1] {\rotatebox[origin=c]{15}{$\displaystyle\int$}}\hss}}
\newcommand{\rint}{\mathop{\bigrint}\displaylimits}

\begin{document}
\[\rint_a^b\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative way which works I believe the same as you want:

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\di}{d\!}

\[
    \int\limits_a^b\! x\di x = \tfrac{1}{2}x^2\Big|_a^b
\]
```