# Rotation in \ddots

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I want to write a math equation that needs power of dots. I tried these code

```
{2^{2^{2^{\ddots^{2}}}}}
```

But the dots needs to be rotated

Comment: @user5376: you could perhaps use egreg's answer to a question  about a rotated integral sign http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17416/create-a-new-integral-symbol/17419#17419

Comment: @user5376: oh, sorry, I thought your dots were already with about the correct angle, as with `\iddots` from [mathdots](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/mathdots). Could prove easier indeed to rotate slightly `\iddots` than a lot `\ddots`, and perhaps actually `\iddots` already quasi solves your problem.

Answer (score 17):

Adapted from The TeXbook, Exercise 18.45:

```
\def\rddots#1{\cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot^{#1}}}}
$ 2^{2^{\rddots2}} $
\bye
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) Again, I feel like it provides a better alignment than `\iddots`!

Comment: When used like this, on math.stackexchange.com each subsequent dot is smaller...

Comment: @Tomáš: That's because MSE uses [mathjax], which is a bit different thing from TeX and I am not very familiar with it. There is a glyph with [unicode-math], `\adots` for U+022F0, but I don't think it's available with mathjax (nor if it's the appropriate glyph for this). If mathjax understands different math `style`s, you could try the more explicit definition: `\def\rddots#1{{\scriptstyle\cdot}^{{\scriptstyle\cdot}^{{\scriptstyle\cdot}^{#1}}}}`

Comment: @TomášZato: Or, with Unicode, something like: `\def\sadots{{\scriptstyle\char"22F0\relax}}` (note that there is no family or class definitions, so for use just in this context).

Answer (score 10):

An easy way would be to replace `\ddots` by `\udots` from the [MnSymbol](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/mnsymbol) package, or `\iddots` from [mathdots](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/mathdots) (better rendering in math mode).

[image]

Comment: I could not define the MnSymbol package, when I define it the program does not compile the file

Comment: @user5376 Add `\usepackage{MnSymbol}` in your preamble. Still, I'd recommend using `\iddots` instead.

Comment: In TexLive you find the package `mathdots` in the package `texlive-generic-extra`

Answer (score 7):

you could try (with 5 dots for the fun of it!):

```
\[
  {2^{2^{2^{\mathstrut^{.^{.^{.^{.^{.^{\raisebox{-.5\height}{$\scriptscriptstyle
                        2$}}}}}}}}}}}
\]

\[
  {2^{2^{2^{\mathstrut^{.^{.^{.^{.^{.^{\raisebox{-.25\height}{$\scriptscriptstyle
                        2$}}}}}}}}}}}
\]
```

or the simpler

```
\[
  {2^{2^{2^{\mathstrut^{.^{.^{.^{\raisebox{-.25\height}{$\scriptscriptstyle
                        2$}}}}}}}}}
\]

\[ 
  {2^{2^{2^{\mathstrut^{.^{.^{.^{2}}}}}}}}
\]
```

they give (respectively):

[image: iterated powers of two]

Comment: @jbfu (+1) Your 2nd solution seems to provide a better alignment.

Comment: @chl yes, I agree. The `\mathstrut` is to put the first dot higher than where it would fall otherwise. One could fine-tune that positioning if needed.