# How to create my own math operator with limits?

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

How can i write my own math operator with limits? I want it to look like: 
`\sum\limits_{e=1}^{m}`
but with a capital A (if possible bigger than the normal text) instead of the sum. 
Thanks for the help!

Comment: See also [positioning - How does a math operator specify the horizontal position of its limits? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/667287/how-does-a-math-operator-specify-the-horizontal-position-of-its-limits) for some options if the math operators aren't horizontally symmetric i.e. you want to put the upper and lower limit not vertically aligned, such as for the ∫ operator.

Answer (score 47):

Use the `\DeclareMathOperator*` command provided by the `amsmath` package. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\Aop}{A}
\begin{document}
\[ \Aop^a_b \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Where is the difference between `\DeclareMathOperator*` and `\DeclareMathOperator`?

Comment: @moose `\DeclareMathOperator*` will use limits so subscript/superscript will go directly below and above the symbol, while `\DeclareMathOperator` will not use limits and so subscript/superscript will go below *right* and above *right*.

Answer (score 46):

We can scale the symbol to the height plus depth of the summation and then vertically center it with respect to the formula axis.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\bigop[1]{%
  \mathop{\vphantom{\sum}\mathpalette\bigop@{#1}}\slimits@
}
\newcommand{\bigop@}[2]{%
  \vcenter{%
    \sbox\z@{$#1\sum$}%
    \hbox{\resizebox{\ifx#1\displaystyle.9\fi\dimexpr\ht\z@+\dp\z@}{!}{$\m@th#2$}}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\bigstar}{\DOTSB\bigop{\star}}
\newcommand{\bigA}{\DOTSB\bigop{\mathrm{A}}}

\begin{document}
\[
\sum_{i=1}^n\bigA_{i=1}^n x_i\dots\bigstar_{i=1}^n x_i
\qquad
\textstyle
\sum\bigA\bigstar_{i=1}^n x_i
\qquad
\scriptstyle
\sum\bigA\bigstar_{i=1}^n x_i
\qquad
\scriptscriptstyle
\sum\bigA\bigstar_{i=1}^n x_i
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

A simpler but not not scalable version (it won't work in

```
\newcommand{\opA}{\mathop{\vphantom{\sum}\mathchoice
  {\vcenter{\hbox{\huge A}}}
  {\vcenter{\hbox{\Large A}}}{\mathrm{A}}{\mathrm{A}}}\displaylimits}
```

In this way the "A" will be as large as the `\sum` symbol.

[image]

An enhanced version, where one can specify a correction factor for the big symbol in display style, as different symbols seem to require different factors.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\bigop[2][1]{%
  \mathop{\vphantom{\sum}\mathpalette\bigop@{{#1}{#2}}}\slimits@
}
\newcommand{\bigop@}[2]{\bigop@@#1#2}
\newcommand{\bigop@@}[3]{%
  \vcenter{%
    \sbox\z@{$#1\sum$}%
    \hbox{\resizebox{\ifx#1\displaystyle#2\fi\dimexpr\ht\z@+\dp\z@}{!}{$\m@th#3$}}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\bigstar}{\DOTSB\bigop{\star}}
\newcommand{\bigA}{\DOTSB\bigop[0.92]{\mathrm{A}}}
\newcommand{\bigDelta}{\DOTSB\bigop[1.05]{\Delta}}

\begin{document}
\[
\sum_{i=1}^n\bigA_{i=1}^n\bigDelta_{i=1}^n x_i\dots\bigstar_{i=1}^n x_i
\]
\begin{center}
$\textstyle
\sum \bigA \bigstar \bigDelta_{i=1}^n x_i
\qquad
\scriptstyle
\sum \bigA \bigstar \bigDelta_{i=1}^n x_i
\qquad
\scriptscriptstyle
\sum \bigA \bigstar \bigDelta_{i=1}^n x_i
$
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\Aop{\operatornamewithlimits{%
  \mathchoice{\vcenter{\hbox{\huge A}}}
             {\vcenter{\hbox{\Large A}}}
             {\mathrm{A}}
             {\mathrm{A}}}}
\begin{document}

\[ \Aop^a_b \sum_a^b \]

$ \Aop^a_b \sum_a^b $

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Use `\mathop` to turn `A` into a "math operator", and then use `\limits` to do sum-style limits:

```
 $$\mathop{A}\limits_{e=1}^{m}$$
```

Do you really want `A`, or do you want `\bigwedge`?

Answer (score 6):

egreg's answer is fine but works poorly for existing mathematical symbols. I recommend the following:

```
\newcommand{\operator}[1]{\mathop{\vphantom{\sum}\mathchoice
{\vcenter{\hbox{\huge $#1$}}}
{\vcenter{\hbox{\Large $#1$}}}{#1}{#1}}\displaylimits}
```

To define an operator 'A', you can now type

```
\newcommand{\opA}{\operator{\mathrm{A}}}
```

But you can also define an operator Theta:

```
\newcommand{\opTheta}{\operator{\Theta}}
```

Just remember that in the argument you pass to `\operator`, you are in math mode.