# How to write larger \natural symbol?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, math-operators

If we want to write big `\sum` symbol, we can write `$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i$`.

I want to do similar thing for `\natural` symbol which will be used to denote the boundary connected sum.

How can I do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23432/how-to-create-my-own-math-operator-with-limits

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Saying `\limits` does not increase the size of the summation symbol, it just moves the limits.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n$ \quad $\sum_{i=1}^n$ \quad
\end{document}
```

If you want to do the same with the `\natural` symbol you need to use `\mathop`.

```
$\natural_{i=1}^n$ \quad $\mathop\natural\limits_{i-1}^n$
```

If you actually want a larger `\natural` you can create one with `\large`, `\Large`, etc.

```
\[ \mathop{\hbox{\Large$\natural$}}\limits_{i=1}^n \natural \]
```

You could also use `\scalebox` from the [graphicx](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/epslatex/english/epslatex.pdf) package.

Answer (score 4):

```
\newcommand{\bignatural}{\mathop{\mathchoice
  {\vcenter{\hbox{\LARGE$\natural$}}}
  {\vcenter{\hbox{\large$\natural$}}}
  {\vcenter{\hbox{\footnotesize$\natural$}}}
  {\vcenter{\hbox{\scriptsize$\natural$}}}
}\displaylimits}
```

Here are examples in the four styles (the `\sum` is for comparison; load **amsmath** for correctly scaling the big operators in script styles)

[image]