# Creating a customizable n-ary operator?

Tags: math-mode, macros, symbols, math-operators

I'd like to be able to create a customizable n-ary operator that behaves like `\sum` or `\bigoplus` but which takes an arbitrary symbol as an argument.

The closest that I have been able to come to achieving this is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{relsize}


\begin{document}
\newcommand{\nop}[1]{\mathop{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{#1}}}}}}

\[ \nop{argument}_{i\in I} g_i \]

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately the vertical spacing is, for lack of a better word, wrong and the space between the symbol and the limits is off as well. To see what's wrong with it try using `\oplus` as the argument and compare it to the output generated by `\bigoplus_{i\in I} g_i`. (If anyone knows how to fix the thickness that would be great too but it's not essential)

What I would like is something more along the lines of the code snippet in one of the answers on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32082/how-to-write-larger-natural-symbol?rq=1) page which is as follows:

```
\newcommand{\bignatural}{\mathop{\mathchoice
  {\vcenter{\hbox{\LARGE$\natural$}}}
  {\vcenter{\hbox{\large$\natural$}}}
  {\vcenter{\hbox{\footnotesize$\natural$}}}
  {\vcenter{\hbox{\scriptsize$\natural$}}}
}\displaylimits}
```

(or the similar code on this [page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23432/how-to-create-my-own-math-operator-with-limits) or this [other](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46356/the-modulo-two-sum-sign-in-latex?rq=1) page) but, unfortunately, I'm not sure of how to go about doing this.

(note: I'm using MiKTeX with TeXstudio)

I'd really appreciate the input of someone who is better versed in LaTeX than I am.

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23432/how-to-create-my-own-math-operator-with-limits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\nop}[1]{\mathop{\mathchoice
  {\vcenter{\hbox{\LARGE$#1$}}}
  {\vcenter{\hbox{\large$#1$}}}
  {\vcenter{\hbox{\footnotesize$#1$}}}
  {\vcenter{\hbox{\scriptsize$#1$}}}
}\displaylimits}
\begin{document}
\[
  \nop{G}_{\text{no operation}} G^{\nop{A}_\text{no operation}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh wow! I was really, really, close when I tried using the code snippet; I was just missing the math delimiters around `#1`.
Thanks! I might do some messing around with the sizing to get it to match up with the other n-ary operators but that's fantastic :D