# How can I make sizes of different symbols equal?

Tags: math-mode, equations

I have an equation like this

```
\begin{gather}
n_i(t-1)= \sum_{j \in S} v_{ij}(t) \\
n_j(t)= \sum_{i \in S} v_{ij}(t) \\
\forall_{t\in T_0} \sum_{i \in S} n_i(t)=N
\end{gather}
```

The third part of it looks bad because `\forall` symbol is much smaller than `\sum` symbol. How can I meke it bigger? I want the `\forall` symbol to have size of `\sum` symbol. I would prefer not to change equation code. I would prefer some changes in preamble.

[image]

Also, is it possible to have `t\in T_0` part below the `\forall` symbol like when using `\sum` symbol?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Very similar to egregs solution in [How to create my own math operator with limits](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23432/how-to-create-my-own-math-operator-with-limits):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\let\stdforall\forall
\renewcommand{\forall}{\mathop{\vphantom{\sum}\mathchoice
  {\vcenter{\hbox{\huge$\stdforall$}}}
  {\vcenter{\hbox{\Large$\stdforall$}}}{\stdforall}{\stdforall}}\displaylimits}
\begin{document}
$\forall_{t\in T_0} \sum_{i \in S} n_i(t)=N$
\[
    \forall_{t\in T_0} \sum_{i \in S} n_i(t)=N
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: auto-sizing forall symbol]