# How to put i=1 to n for a \square?

Tags: math-operators

Here's the i=1 to n for a `\bigwedge`

```
 \documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
 \usepackage{ amssymb }
 \begin{document}
$ \bigwedge\limits_{i=1}^n t_1 $

 \end{document}
```

How do I do it for a `\square` (it doesn't work if I replace `\bigwedge` with `\square`), it gives an error that `\limit` can only be used for math operators.

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23432/how-to-create-my-own-math-operator-with-limits

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may want to use `\bigboxvoid` from the `mathabx` package, with the usual caution about the package changing many symbols. If you want only that symbol, then the procedure outlined in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14388/4427) can be employed; the symbol will change sizes just like `\sum` or `\bigwedge` and accept limits in displaystyle as shown in the example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ amsmath, amssymb }
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10>
      <10.95> <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88>
      mathx10
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bigboxvoid}{1}{mathx}{"DC}

\begin{document}
$\displaystyle\bigboxvoid_{i=1}^n$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You need to define it as a math operator.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{ amsmath, amssymb }
\DeclareMathOperator*{\sq}{\square}
\begin{document}
$\sq_{i=1}^n$
\end{document}
```

See [How to create my own math operator with limits?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23432/how-to-create-my-own-math-operator-with-limits)