# Text across several summation symbols

Tags: math-mode

I have a question on how to have the following in an equation.

Here is some working code to start with:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
P(X)=\sum_{X\in A}\cdots \sum
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `\underset` from [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
P(X)=\underset{X\in A}{\sum \cdots \sum}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If this is a common occurrence in your document, you might consider creating it as a new operator with limits, which is discussed in [How to create my own math operator with limits?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23432/how-to-create-my-own-math-operator-with-limits) and in percusse's answer to your question here.

Answer (score 16):

Here is one way via declaring an operator

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} %<-- loads, enhances amsmath
\DeclareMathOperator*{\manysum}{\sum\cdots\sum}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
P(X)=\manysum_{X\in A}(x_{ijklm})
\end{equation}
Also inline \(P(X)=\manysum_{X\in A}(x_{ijklm})\).
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 13):

A more general answer:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Multi@Sum}[1]{%
  \ifcase#1\relax\or
    \or
    \sum\sum\or
    \sum\sum\sum\else
    \sum\dots\sum
  \fi
}
\newcommand\ssum{\DOTSB\mathop{\Multi@Sum{2}}\slimits@}
\newcommand\sssum{\DOTSB\mathop{\Multi@Sum{3}}\slimits@}
\newcommand\sdotssum{\DOTSB\mathop{\Multi@Sum{-1}}\slimits@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\sum_{x\in A}\quad
\ssum_{x\in A}\quad
\sssum_{x\in A}\quad
\sdotssum_{x\in A}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This will respect the option `nosumlimit` or `sumlimit` (default) given to `amsmath`.

You may want to change the `\sum\dots\sum` line to

```
\sum\!\cdots\!\sum
```

getting, for `\sdotssum_{x\in A}` the output

[image]