# Need to create a specific notation

Tags: equations

I need a symbol as below.

[image]

How can I create it?

Comment: Is that a capital lambda or a big wedge?

Comment: $$\Lambda{}^{\mathbf{a}}_{\mathbf{b}}$$?

Comment: @aidangallagher4 This is not exactly what I need. The wedge sign is too small and whatever I did to make it larger, it didn't work.

Comment: @daleif No matter what it is, until the result is reasonably similar to the image I inserted.

Comment: It’s unclear exactly what you’re looking for here, but if you want something which replicates exactly what you drew there, I’d look into tikz

Comment: Variable sized operators use special font characters. This group includes \sum, \prod, \int and \bigwedge among others. I did find a \bigcurlywedge and \bigwedgedot in the comprehensive symbol list.  Are you sure you want to use a symbol no one else has ever used?

Comment: I recommend you change the question title to something more descriptive, such as "Serifed big wedge operator" or "Big wedge operator with serifs" (or whatever the actual name of the operator is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used `tikz` to create such an operator based on [How to create my own math operator with limits?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23432/how-to-create-my-own-math-operator-with-limits)

However you might need to modify it accordingly to get it to look "good", since I used some random values for the dimensions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\nwedge}
{\operatorname{\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[line width=0.1mm] (0,0)--(0.2,0.6)--(0.4,0);
        \draw[line width=0.1mm] (-0.06,0)--(0.06,0);
        \draw[line width=0.1mm] (0.34,0)--(0.46,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}}}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\bigop[1]{%
    \mathop{\vphantom{\sum}\mathpalette\bigop@{#1}}\nolimits@
}
\newcommand{\bigop@}[2]{%
    \vcenter{%
        \sbox\z@{$#1\sum$}%
        \hbox{\resizebox{\ifx#1\displaystyle.9\fi\dimexpr\ht\z@+\dp\z@}{!}{$\m@th#2$}}%
    }%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\bigV}[2]{{\bigop{\nwedge}}^{\textrm{\textbf{#1}}}_{\textrm{\textbf{#2}}}}

\begin{document}
$\nwedge_{a}^b$  some random text $\bigV{a}{b} $

\[\bigV{a}{b}\]
\end{document}
```

The `\nwedge` command doesn't scale when used inline. The scaling is based on the `\sum`  operator.

[image]