# Large greek letters

Tags: math-operators

For products and summations there are `\prod` and `\sum`, which are larger than normal greek letters and accepts limits. I need the same thing for a capital delta, does this exists?

Edit to clarify: I don't need only the limits, I need the delta to be larger. I don't think it's just scaling up the symbol, since that will make it look unusually fat. Compare the sum / product with my solution using raisebox & scalebox:

[image]

Comment: This is most likely a duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create my own math operator with limits?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23432/how-to-create-my-own-math-operator-with-limits)

Comment: I don't mean it as how to create limits, I need a larger greek letter mostly.

Comment: I've solved my problem: $\huge\Delta$ does not work, but \huge$\Delta$ does.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because OP solved it himself as stated in the comments below the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see codes for the big DELTA in the following.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\newcommand{\bigdelta}{\raisebox{-.35\baselineskip}{\huge\ensuremath{\Delta}}}
\newcommand{\bigdeltab}{\makebox{\huge\ensuremath{\Delta}}}

\begin{document}

So this is the very big $\bigdelta$ what you want. And it act between lines like:
\[\bigdelta x=mn=\prod=0.\]

And we can we have another kind of big $\bigdeltab$ which acts between lines like:
\[\bigdeltab x=mn=\prod=0.\]

\end{document}
```

The compiled PDF is

[image]