# Using a primed sum operator in display and text mode

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I would like to define a *primed* sum command `\sump` such that `\sump_{x \in X}` produces:

- a prime at the top right corner and the `x \in X` below the sigma in display mode, and
- a prime in the top right corner and the `x \in X` at the bottom right of the sigma in text mode.

I've tried combinations of `\mathchoice` and `\sideset` to get this right, but have not succeeded so far.

If it makes any difference, I'd like to do this not only with sums, but also to define primed `\prod`, `\min` and `\max` commands.

Of course, one could define `\sump` to take the `x \in X` as an argument, and then place it correctly using `\mathchoice` and `\sideset`, but for writing code that is more readable and includes normal (non-primed) sums I'd prefer not to do this. Help?

If one follows the most accepted answer in the suggested [How to create my own math operator with limits?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23432/how-to-create-my-own-math-operator-with-limits), then when using `\sump_{x \in X}` in text mode there is an unnecessary space before the `x \in X` lower limit; the prime pushes the right boundary of the operator out, so that the lower limit doesn't start right next to the `Sigma`.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23432/how-to-create-my-own-math-operator-with-limits seems related.

Comment: in particular `\DeclareMathOperator*{\sump}{\Sigma'}` seems an easy solution.

Comment: or `\DeclareMathOperator*{\sump}{\Sigma^{\prime}}` for a more math-like prime.

Comment: @Marijn Ah, a combination of `\DeclareMathOperator` and `\DeclareMathoperator*` and `\mathchoice` might work...

Comment: The `\mathchoice` may not be necessary, the subscript position and size seems fine with just `\DeclareMathOperator*`. But of course you can choose any implementation you'd like :) Meanwhile I think it would be best to close this question as a duplicate of the other one.

Comment: The way I read this is that the spacing is to be the same as an unembellished `\sum`; there may or may not be an upper limit.  If there is no upper limit except in a display environment, then `\sum^{\rlap{\prime}}` might work.  (I'm unable to test, so this is just a suggestion.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I seem to get some strange errors about missing `$` and `}` signs...

Comment: This is *precisely* the main point of Exercise 18.44 of _The TeXbook_.  Knuth gives two solutions: the first, in practice equivalent to `\DeclareMathOperator*{\sump}{{\sum}'}`, is slightly defective (why? ;-) ; the second, more sophisticated, is too complex to be repeated in a comment.  See the solution of the exercise in _The TeXbook_.

Comment: @LiamBaker -- That should have been `\mathrlap`,  Requires `mathtools`.

Comment: @GuM Thanks for the pointer! If you put the second solution from _the TeXbook_ into an answer, I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: @barbarabeeton your suggestion works well in text mode, but not in display mode (since the prime then goes above the `\sum`. Strangely enough, your suggestion doesn't seem to work in text mode when wrapped in a `\mathchoice`...

Comment: To Liam Baker:  But the second solution from _The TeXbook_ breaks two of the requirements that you state in your question: it works only in displayed formulas, and absorbs the subscript as an argument.  Also, I think that @barbarabeeton actually meant `\mathop{{\sum}^{\mathrlap{\prime}}}`.

Comment: I don’t think that any of the answers to the [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23432/69818) of which this one is supposed to be a duplicate actually addresses the problem asked about here; so I’m voting to reopen this question.

Comment: @GuM to be honest, I don't mind that the second solution from the TeXbook absorbs the subscript as an argument, since the subscript notation is still used in the code and hence is readable.

Comment: @GuM also, I've tested the code in both text and display mode, and it seems to work well in both.

Comment: @LiamBaker: Beware, however, that the prime may bump into an adjacent symbol (_e.g._, a left bracket), since it is not taken into account when computing the width of the `\sump` operator.  By the way, I’ve just realized that I had never upvoted your question: fixed! ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You can test for `_` after `\sump` with the help of `xparse`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\sump}{e{_}}
 {%
  \DOTSB
  \mathop{\IfNoValueTF{#1}{\sump@{}}{\sump@{#1}}}%
  \nolimits
 }
\newcommand{\sump@}[1]{\mathpalette\sump@@{#1}}
\newcommand{\sump@@}[2]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle
    {\sump@display{#2}}%
  \else
    \sum@\nolimits'_{#2}%
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\sump@display}[1]{%
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th\displaystyle\sum@\nolimits'$}%
  \sbox\tw@{$\m@th\displaystyle\sum@\limits_{#1}$}%
  \sbox\@tempboxa{$\m@th\displaystyle'$}
  \mathop{\sum@\nolimits' \kern-\wd\@tempboxa}\limits_{#1}%
  \ifdim\wd\z@>\wd\tw@
    \kern\dimexpr\wd\z@-\wd\tw@\relax
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
&\sum_{n} a_n &&\textstyle \sum_{n\ge0} a_n \\
&\sump_{n} a_n &&\textstyle \sump_{n\ge0} a_n \\
&\sum_{n\ge0} a_n &&\textstyle \sum_{n\ge0} a_n \\
&\sump_{n\ge0} a_n &&\textstyle \sump_{n\ge0} a_n \\
&\sum_{1\le n\le 32} a_n &&\textstyle \sum_{1\le n\le 32} a_n \\
&\sump_{1\le n\le 32} a_n &&\textstyle \sump_{1\le n\le 32} a_n
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the “nondisplay” case just typeset `\sum'_{#1}`, in the display case I measure the prime, so to kern and produce the subscript centered on the summation symbol. Then I measure the summation with the prime and the summation with the subscript, in order to decide whether some kerning is necessary, which it is if the size of “primed summation” exceeds the size of “summation with subscript”.

Comment: This is what I was deliberately trying to avoid, since the OP seemed to dismiss this type of solution, at least in the question.  But it’s also true that (s)he [seems to have changed her/his mind](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506497/using-a-primed-sum-operator-in-display-and-text-mode?noredirect=1#comment1287844_506497) later on, so… +1! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

As already said in the comments, this problem is the main subject of Exercise 18.44 of *The TeXbook*.  Barbara Beeton has already [suggested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506497/using-a-primed-sum-operator-in-display-and-text-mode#comment1279690_506497) a variation of one of the two solutions that Knuth presents in Appendix A, although her code should be modified to read, more or less,

```
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\sump}{%
    \mathop{{\sum}^{\mathrlap{\prime}}}%
}
```

Here’s a complete, compilable example, that also draws attention to a possible flaw of this solution:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand*{\sump}{} % check that the name can be used
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\sump}{%
    \mathop{{\sum}^{\mathrlap{\prime}}}%
}



\begin{document}

First in-line:
\( \sump_{i\in I}a_{i} \ne \sum_{i\in I}a_{i} \).
Then in display:
\[
    \sump_{i\in I}a_{i} \ne \sum_{i\in I}a_{i}
    \mbox{.}
\]

You can also say, for instance,
\( \sump\limits_{i\in I}a_{i} \ne \sum\limits_{i\in I}a_{i} \)
and
\[
    \sump\nolimits_{i\in I}a_{i} \ne \sum\nolimits_{i\in I}a_{i}
    \mbox{,}
\]
respectively.

There's a caveat, though: because the prime is not taken into account
when computing the width of the \verb|\sump| symbol, it may bump into
adjacent characters:
\[
    \sump \biggl[\frac{a+b}{c+d}-\frac{x+y}{x-y}\biggr]
        \ne \sum \biggl[\frac{a+b}{c+d}-\frac{x+y}{x-y}\biggr]
\]
The clash is more problematic in in-line math:
\( \sump[a+b] \ne \sum[a+b] \).
However, in practice this is not going to be a problem if you stick to
using the \verb|\sump| symbol only with a (non-empty) subscript.

\end{document}
```

However, if we have to load the `mathtools` package, which, in turn, requires `amsmath`, I think we should also support the [`no`]`sumlimits` option of the latter, as well as its `\dots` feature:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

% Try decommenting the following line:
% \usepackage[nosumlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter

% Cannot directly use "\DeclareRobustCommand" with "\DOTSB":
\@ifdefinable\sump@{\DeclareRobustCommand*\sump@{%
    \mathop{{\sum}^{\mathrlap{\prime}}}%
}}
\newcommand*\sump{%
    \DOTSB\sump@\slimits@ % ...or move "\slimits@" into "\sump@"
}

\makeatother



\begin{document}

First in-line:
\( \sump_{i\in I}a_{i} \ne \sum_{i\in I}a_{i} \).
Then in display:
\begin{equation}
    \sump_{i\in I}a_{i} \ne \sum_{i\in I}a_{i}
    \mbox{.}
    \label{eq:displaylimits}
\end{equation}

You can also say, for instance,
\( \sump\limits_{i\in I}a_{i} \ne \sum\limits_{i\in I}a_{i} \)
and
\[
    \sump\nolimits_{i\in I}a_{i} \ne \sum\nolimits_{i\in I}a_{i}
    \mbox{,}
\]
respectively.  And see what happens in the ``default'' case (that is,
in~\eqref{eq:displaylimits}) if you load the \textsf{amsmath} package
with the \texttt{nosumlimits} option.

Finally, note that
\( \sump_{i_{1}}\dots\sump_{i_{p}} x_{i_{1}}\otimes\dots\otimes x_{i_{p}} \)
works exactly in the same way as
\( \sum_{i_{1}}\dots\sum_{i_{p}} x_{i_{1}}\otimes\dots\otimes x_{i_{p}} \)
(as one would expect).  Let's repeat it in display:
\[
    \sump_{i_{1}}\dots\sump_{i_{p}} x_{i_{1}}\otimes\dots\otimes x_{i_{p}}
    \ne
    \sum_{i_{1}}\dots\sum_{i_{p}} x_{i_{1}}\otimes\dots\otimes x_{i_{p}}
\]
(this way the formula is more readable!).

\typeout{A test for robustness: \sump}
\typeout{Compare the above with \sum}

\end{document}
```

Note that the above code (the second MWE) writes a couple of messages during the compilation, which exemplify how the `\sump` command is written out to auxiliary files, and shows that its behavior in this respect parallels that of `\sum`.