# Typesetting completed direct sum

Tags: symbols, math-operators, accents

I'm trying to typeset a completed direct sum. This is traditionally written
as a `\bigoplus` with a hat (really, a `\widehat`) above it. What is the recommended way to do this?

I can think of two solutions, but neither is optimal.

- `\widehat{\bigoplus_i} V_i` has too little spacing between the summation symbol and the argument.
- `{\widehat\bigoplus}_i V_i` has the index to the right of the summation symbol instead of beneath it, and it doesn't appear possible to fix this using `\limits`.

Comment: The answers at the following URL might help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23432/how-to-create-my-own-math-operator-with-limits

Comment: What about `\widehat{\bigoplus_i} V_i \neq \mathop{\widehat{\bigoplus_i}} V_i`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to use `\mathop{\widehat{\bigoplus}}`. Here I also adorn the construction to be the same as the other big operators in `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\cbigoplus}{\DOTSB\cbigoplus@\slimits@}
\newcommand{\cbigoplus@}{\mathop{\widehat{\bigoplus}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\bigoplus_{i\in I}V_i \hookrightarrow \cbigoplus_{i\in I}V_i
\]
\[
\cbigoplus_{i\in I}V_i \hookleftarrow \bigoplus_{i\in I}V_i
\]
\begin{center} % just to make a smaller picture
$\bigoplus_{i\in I}V_i \hookrightarrow \cbigoplus_{i\in I}V_i$ \\
$\cbigoplus_{i\in I}V_i \hookleftarrow \bigoplus_{i\in I}V_i$ 
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]