# How to define a \bigplus operator in plain TeX?

Tags: math-operators, plain-tex

How to define a big plus operator that behaves exactly like `bigsum` but uses the plus symbol instead of a capital sigma?

I know that the best option (or at least the way Don would do it) is probably to design this symbol using metafont but scaling is good enough for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

You can use `\mathchoice` to use a suitably scaled font in each math style.

```
\font \zzz = cmr10 at 14pt
\font\zzzb  cmr10 at 20pt
\font\zzzsy =cmsy10 at 14pt
\font\zzzsyb =cmsy10 at 20pt

\def\bigplus{\mathop{\mathchoice{\hbox{\zzzb+}}{\hbox{\zzz+}}{\scriptstyle+}{\scriptscriptstyle+}}}
\def\bigtimes{\mathop{\mathchoice{\hbox{\zzzsyb\char2}}{\hbox{\zzzsy\char2}}{\scriptstyle\times}{\scriptscriptstyle\times}}}

\def\test{\sum_{i=0}^nx^i \rightarrow \bigplus_{i=0}^nx^i \rightarrow \bigtimes_{i=0}^nx^i}
$$
\test
$$
or..

\bigskip

This $\test$

\bigskip

Or this $x^{\test}$
\bye
```

Or with vertical center for Barbara

[image]

```
\def\bigplus{\mathop{\mathchoice{\vcenter{\hbox{\zzzb+}}}{\vcenter{\hbox{\zzz+}}}{\scriptstyle+}{\scriptscriptstyle+}}}
\def\bigtimes{\mathop{\mathchoice{\vcenter{\hbox{\zzzsyb\char2}}}{\vcenter{\hbox{\zzzsy\char2}}}{\scriptstyle\times}{\scriptscriptstyle\times}}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't understand why the same font isn't used in the two examples and what's the meaning of zzz, thank you

Comment: @Laravel + comes from the roman font and \times comes from the symbols font in the default plain tex layout.  zzz is just a name you could call them `\bigrm`  `\biggerrm`, `\bigsym`, `\biggersym` if you prefer.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense! Were the 14pt and 20pt values chosen arbitrarily?

Comment: yes I just did it by eye. @Laravel

Comment: You really want to treat those enlarged symbols like "large operators' so that they're centered vertically on the math axis.  (Please!)  By the way, the selection of 20pt and 14pt are appropriate.]; that's what was used when this had to be done at AMS.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I made them \mathop oh you want them vcentred as well? hmm I guess so let me try that...

Comment: @barbarabeeton at your service....

Comment: Oh, that's *much* better!  (I.e., correctly placed.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I even spelled centre incorrectly for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with scaling, provided you load `eplain`. The following code is based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23436/4427. The idea is to measure `\sum` in the current math style and to scale the chosen symbol to match.

Experiment and choose the right factor for `\genericbigop` and the chosen symbol.

```
\input eplain
\beginpackages
\usepackage{graphicx}
\endpackages

% add scaled versions of the cmex font
\font\sevenex=cmex7
\font\fiveex=cmex7 at 5pt
\scriptfont3=\sevenex
\scriptscriptfont3=\fiveex
%

\catcode`@=11
\def\genericbigop#1#2{% #1=factor, #2=symbol
  \mathop{\vphantom{\sum}\mathpalette\genericbigop@{{#1}{#2}}}\displaylimits
}
\def\genericbigop@#1#2{\genericbigop@@#1#2}
\def\genericbigop@@#1#2#3{%
  \vcenter{%
    \setbox\z@=\hbox{$#1\sum$}%
    \dimen@=\ht\z@ \advance\dimen@\dp\z@
    \hbox{\resizebox{#2\dimen@}{!}{$\m@th#3$}}%
  }%
}
\catcode`@=12

\def\bigplus{\genericbigop{1.1}{+}}
\def\bigtimes{\genericbigop{1.1}{\times}}

$$
\sum_{i=0}^nx^i \quad \bigplus_{i=0}^nx^i \quad \bigtimes_{i=0}^nx^i
$$
\centerline{%
  $\sum_{i=0}^nx^i \quad \bigplus_{i=0}^nx^i \quad \bigtimes_{i=0}^nx^i$
}
\centerline{%
  $\scriptstyle\sum_{i=0}^nx^i \quad \bigplus_{i=0}^nx^i \quad \bigtimes_{i=0}^nx^i$
}
\centerline{%
  $\scriptscriptstyle\sum_{i=0}^nx^i \quad \bigplus_{i=0}^nx^i \quad \bigtimes_{i=0}^nx^i$
}

\bye
```

[image]