# import \mathbb{1} from dsserif without changing other \mathbb{}

Tags: fonts, pdftex, math-fonts, mathbb

In pdflatex, I'd like to use `\mathbb{1}` in a way suggested in  [How do you get \mathbb{1} to work?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26637/how-do-you-get-mathbb1-to-work-characteristic-function-of-a-set); that is:

```
\usepackage[bb=dsserif]{mathalpha}
\def\1\mathbb{1}
\[\1\]
```

But, a side effect (for me) is that it also changes other fonts such as `\mathbb{R}`

Is there any way I can just import a single symbol `\mathbb{1}` from `dsserif`, defining it as `\1` without changing other fonts?

---

EDIT:
Based on user202729's comment, I figured out a way:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
%\DeclareFontFamily{U}{DSSerif}{\skewchar \font =45}% openface
%\DeclareFontShape{U}{DSSerif}{m}{n}{<-> s*[1]  DSSerif}{}
%\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{DSSerif}{m}{n}
%\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbbbb}{U}{DSSerif}{m}{n}
\def\1{{\usefont{U}{DSSerif}{m}{n}1}}
\begin{document}
\1
\end{document}
```

My follow up questions are:

1. is the four lines commented out above really unnecessary? It seems
   that `\1` works well without those four lines, but just want to make
   sure.
2. `\1` works well when I use it in a text mode, but it fails to work once I use it in a math mode (e.g., `\[\1\]`). Why and how to fix it?

Comment: You'll most likely inevitably have to copy paste some code from the package source code. [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @user202729 Thanks. I also read that post and a few others, but quite difficult for me to understand what's going on.

Comment: (as I've explained above, the code is copy pasted from the package source code)

Comment: Thanks. I'll read the implementation of it.

Comment: Okay, great that you (seems to...? only in text mode?) solved the issue, although I think it's better (? .note. not sure on this one) to post that part as an answer and post a separate question for the follow-up.

Comment: I guess you can \text {} it https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/628706/using-math-mode-with-custom-font-character-in-latex-overleaf#comment1567930_628706 , although I'm not sure if the spacing is correct or if it has some other issues.

Comment: `\def\1{\textrm{\usefont{U}{DSSerif}{m}{n}1}}` works. Thanks! (not sure this is the best way though)