How to load a math glyph and set it up like \int
I want to modify the glyph for the integral, and then use it as \myint sometimes in place of \int. For this reason i need to figure out how to load the integral glyph from some font and give it the typical \int look (using Lualatex). Lets take latin modern as an example font, download the math part of it from LM Math download.
Currently i get this:

Please note the superfluos space after the integral and the limits being out of place. My question is: How do i fix these two things?
The code that produced the above is:
% !TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass[ngerman,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
%\usepackage{newcomputermodern}

% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/439983/294323
\newfontface{\mysymbolsfontface}{latinmodern-math.otf}[
    %Path = ./,          % Adjust the path to where the font is located
    Extension = .otf,
    NFSSFamily=mysymbolsfontfamily %use some name for the font family
]
\DeclareSymbolFont{mysymbolsfont}{TU}{mysymbolsfontfamily}{m}{n}
\Umathchardef\displaymyint="1 \symmysymbolsfont "222B %"\sym" then symbolsfontname then glyph code. The "1 stands for mathoperator
\Umathchardef\inlinemyint="1 \symmysymbolsfont "222B

\DeclareRobustCommand\myint{\mathchoice
{\displaymyint\nolimits}
{\inlinemyint\nolimits}
{\inlinemyint\nolimits}
{\inlinemyint\nolimits}}



\begin{document}

Inline: \qquad\qquad\qquad \fbox{$\myint$} \quad \fbox{$\myint_\infty^\infty g(x)$}\\
Displaymode: \qquad\qquad\qquad \fbox{$\displaystyle\myint$} \quad \fbox{$\displaystyle\myint_\infty^\infty g(x)$}\\

Supposed Inline: \quad \fbox{$\int$} \quad \fbox{$\int_\infty^\infty g(x)$}\\
Supposed Displaymode: \quad \fbox{$\displaystyle\int$} \quad \fbox{$\displaystyle\int_\infty^\infty g(x)$}\\
\end{document}


oh, right. I forgot latin modern is probably installed. Done. I will need it again later, when i supply my own font though

Shouldnt the answer to this be somewhere in any fonts package, e.g. lmodern? If so i cant find it...

no, I'm not sure actually it should just be enough to declare \displaymyint (you don't need the inline one as it's identical)  the switching of glyphs is implemented within the font, but classically only fam3, but in luatex it's any family (I thought) but I can only make it happen for the main family (as done by unicode-math) if you declare it for a new fam then it always uses the text size. If the font doesn't implememt the two glyphs then you would need a mathchoice construct see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/618129/1090

i will need both inline and display to be different, they are only set to the same because it autoswitches. A Mathchoice construct is totally fine, but i need to get the space and the limits right.
Why isnt this part of lmodern package? Like where is it set that the limits appear right for \int but not in my setup?

as I say mathchoice isn't needed for the latin modern int (or int in any math font) as the switch to the display style glyph is implemented by the font so to see how to use \mathchoice you need to see examples using a symbol not supplied in two sizes by the font such as the + example I link to above.

I think you misunderstand me. My Problem is not with the autoswitching but with getting the limits of the integral properly aligned and the bounding box to be normal (as in with \int)

you have \nolimitsin the wrong place it should be outside the mathchoice, see the example I link to, but the problem with this example is that the int does not get bigger as the font specified display  int is not selected even in the displaystyle branch of mathchoice, but if that was fixed you would not need mathchoice at all as then it would work like the standard\int. Perhaps you should pick an example not using \int`  then it would be a duplicate question

I dont get it: Moving the \nolimits out of the mathchoice and using \mathop doesnt fix any of the two issues. I mean it should still fix the alignment even if we currently have the same integral in both cases, but we can always replace the displaystyle case later with a custom .otf file which gives different symbols.

If it is doing any help, i can provide a custom .otf that has different glyphs for the two integral styles

https://we.tl/t-dO0HcuvMsE
Here is a otf file that provides the textstyle integral under 222B and the display integral under 002A.
Using it with
`\Umathchardef\displaymyint="1 \symmysymbolsfont "002A %"\sym" then symbolsfontname then glyph code. The "1 stands for mathoperator
\Umathchardef\inlinemyint="1 \symmysymbolsfont "222B
\DeclareRobustCommand\myint{\mathop{\mathchoice
{\displaymyint}
{\inlinemyint}
{\inlinemyint}
{\inlinemyint}}\nolimits}
`
fixes the width problem but not the alignment problem of the limits

you would need to pull the limits inside the mathchoice or shift them by hand as a \mathchoice makes a rectangular \hbox so you lose the font specified cut in of the subscript, it's like \hbox{$\int$}_a^b  the scripts are on the outer list not on the character. there are examples on this site if you search for \mathchoice, but the example in the question (with \int)  is probably soluable by not using \mathchoice at all

Even if i use arguments to the command like in
\DeclareRobustCommand\myint[2]{\mathop{\mathchoice {\displaymyint\nolimits_{#1}^{#2}} {\inlinemyint\nolimits_{#1}^{#2}} {\inlinemyint\nolimits_{#1}^{#2}} {\inlinemyint\nolimits_{#1}^{#2}}}}
it doesnt work in either case
Or simply $\displaymyint_1^2$ doesnt work

So that means even if we forget about choosing the correctly styled glyph, simply picking the small integral glyph and putting limits on it, doesnt work - basically reenacting the definition of \int. How?
really

Ok, lets leave out all the mode switching and just try to get a correct inline style integral.
Why do the limits work indented but with too much whitespace when i use latinmodern-math.otf
vs incorrectly with my above-sent latinmodern-math_both_integrals (which doesnt change any integral signs, it simply overwrites some other letter with another copy of the displaysize integral)? How is it so hard to reenact the definition of \int from an external otf?

I showed you in my answer that if you load a different Unicode math font with a new math font family number, then you can define \myintop using \Umatchardef primitive and you can add \nolimits in your \myint macro. The size of the integral symbol (depending on math style) is solved inside the Unicode math font. I.e. all four sizes are connected to single Unicode slot ("222B in this case). You don't have to worry about these sizes at macro level, the font takes care of that. The only problem: I don't know how LaTeX can load a math font under a given math font family number.

When you use Unicode Math fonts (for example latinmodern-math.otf as basic font and texgyrepagella-math.otf for alternative characters, then all works without problems. I tried this by OpTeX:
\fontfam[lm]  % latinmodern-math is loaded here
\addUmathfont \pagella {[texgyrepagella-math]]}{} {}{} {} % load font and register it at math-font family \pagella
\Umathchardef\myintop 1 \pagella `∫  \protected\def\myint{\myintop\nolimits} % \myint declaration

Test: $\int_a^b f(x), \myint_a^b f(x), \displaystyle \myint_a^b f(x) $

\bye

I have chosen Pagella in order you can see that the integral symbol was really used in the \myint macro. You can use your special font instead it, of course.
OpTeX runs with LuaTeX. You mentioned that you are using LuaLaTeX which runs with LuaTeX too. This means that in LuaLaTeX should be no problems too, but I don't know LaTeX, so don't expect LaTeX related advices from me

i tried compiling with lualatex (which works on my system, see my use of \usepackage{fontspec} but it doesnt compile.
This however doesnt look like what i need (guessing from the code):
I need an additonal comand \myint that typesets a certain glyph from my otf file. This glyph will be a variant of an integral, so it needs to have properly spaced limits. It should either autochoose the correct char by math style or typeset another glyph depending on math style.

@Rubids OK, I edited my answer in order to add the \myint macro which uses \myintop from \pagella math family. And \int macro is unchanged. This is simpler task, I used only TeX primitives at line 3 of my code, so this can be used in LuaLaTeX too. Moreower, I wrote that my code isn't LaTeX but OpTeX, so it can be compiled by optex command. You have this command ready if you have TeXlive distribution with optex package.

This is sadly of no use to me: First i wont switch to optex in any forseeable future, secondly you simply use the \myintop defined by another package. I dont have a font package which provides any commands i only have my selfmade otf, so you would actually have to select the glyph and make it behave like it is supposed to.

@Rubids I don't suppose that you will switch to OpTeX. My answer only demonstrates that your issue is possible to solve very simply. The line 3 of my answer is applicable in LaTeX because there are only TeX primitives. The only problem remains: how to do \addUmathfont \mathfamily  in LaTeX. I supposed that this can answer LaTeX experts here or you will read in a huge LaTeX documentation about it. Note that math font family is named math group in LaTeX because LaTeX often inappropriately uses different than TeX terminology.
