How to write below boolean symbols in latex?
I want to write something like

but simply writing _ after \land does not work.

You can use the \mathop  like so, \mathop{\land}_{1\leq i \leq k}.

\bigwedge_{1\leq i\leq k}

Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23432/how-to-create-my-own-math-operator-with-limits

Most binary operation symbols have an “n-ary” counterpart:

+ has \sum
\cdot has \prod
\oplus has \bigoplus
\vee has \bigvee
\wedge has \bigwedge

and others. For historical reasons, \vee and \wedge have the alternate names \lor and \land, but the “big” versions don't.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\bigvee_{1\leq k\leq n} a_k = a_1\lor a_2\lor \dots \lor a_n
\\
\bigwedge_{1\leq k\leq n} a_k = a_1\land a_2\land \dots \land a_n
\end{gather*}

\end{document}


You might prefer to have \biglor and \blgland:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \NewCommandCopy{\biglor}{\bigvee}%
  \NewCommandCopy{\bigland}{\bigwedge}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\biglor_{1\leq k\leq n} a_k = a_1\lor a_2\lor \dots \lor a_n
\\
\bigland_{1\leq k\leq n} a_k = a_1\land a_2\land \dots \land a_n
\end{gather*}

\end{document}

The output is the same.
Note. The \AtBeginDocument is not really necessary with pdflatex, but it is if you use unicode-math and XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.
