Too much space below a big operator
I'd like to reduce the space between a large operator and the material below it. Is there an elegant way to achieve that?

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{relsize}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\@big@star@}{\Huge\mathlarger{\mathlarger{*}}}
\newlength{\@big@star@vshift@}
\setlength{\@big@star@vshift@}{3pt}

\newcommand{\bigstar}{%
  \mathop{\raisebox{-\@big@star@vshift@}{$\@big@star@$}}%
}

\newcommand{\@big@compo@}{\Huge\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\circ}}}
\newlength{\@big@compo@vshift@}
\setlength{\@big@compo@vshift@}{4pt}

\newcommand{\bigcompo}{%
  \mathop{\raisebox{-\@big@compo@vshift@}{$\@big@compo@$}}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

Example 1: $\displaystyle \bigstar_{XXX}^{ppp} s_i$

Example 2: $\displaystyle \bigcompo_{XXX}^{ppp} f_k$

\end{document}


relsize isn't the best tool for this and \Huge is not legal in math mode.
Anyway, the issue is due to how * and \circ sit in their bounding boxex. I suggest to use the macros in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23436/4427 (last version) and to move the \circ symbol a bit down.
I use \bigast because star refers to a five pointed symbol.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\bigop[2][1]{%
  \mathop{\vphantom{\sum}\mathpalette\bigop@{{#1}{#2}}}\slimits@
}
\newcommand{\bigop@}[2]{\bigop@@#1#2}
\newcommand{\bigop@@}[3]{%
  \vcenter{%
    \sbox\z@{$#1\sum$}%
    \hbox{\resizebox{\ifx#1\displaystyle#2\fi\dimexpr\ht\z@+\dp\z@}{!}{$\m@th#3$}}%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\lcirc}{\mathpalette\lcirc@\relax}
\newcommand{\lcirc@}[2]{\raisebox{-0.1\height}[0.9\height][0pt]{$\m@th#1\circ$}}
\makeatother


\newcommand{\bigast}{\DOTSB\bigop{*}}
\newcommand{\bigcompo}{\DOTSB\bigop[1.1]{\lcirc}}

\begin{document}

% show the bounding boxes
{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fbox{$\circ$}\fbox{$\lcirc$}\fbox{$\ast$}}

Example 1: $\displaystyle \bigast_{XXX}^{ppp} s_i$

Example 2: $\displaystyle \bigcompo_{XXX}^{ppp} f_k$

\end{document}



Here I am well instructed and obliged to fully respect the proposed solution. :-) Thank you very much.

Is this solution could be l3-ifiable?

@projetmbc Why?

Simple curiosity.

Why do you use \DOTSB when  latexdef -p amsmath \DOTSB gives \DOTSB: \relax?

@projetmbc For correct behavior with \dots. Look at how amsmath defines \sum.

One last question. I prefer to use \NewDocumentCommand, keeping \newcommand for zero argument cases. Is there a L3 version of \DeclareRobustCommand, or using \NewDocumentCommand is ok?

@projetmbc Use \NewDocumentCommand if you prefer.

One very last question. I can't figure out what is the 3rd argument of \bigop@@ (the 1st one is the style from \mathpalette, the 2nd one the material for the new operator).

@projetmbc In this case #3 is the material to be typeset, while #2 is the optional different magnification to use in display style.

Thanks for all!

Why \DOTSB is not put directly in the macro \bigop?
