# How to represent the trace of a matrix

Tags: math-mode, matrices, math-operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Define additional math operators to be typeset in roman](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/671/define-additional-math-operators-to-be-typeset-in-roman)

The trace of a matrix is often written as "Tr [matrix] ", but there does not seem to be a naive LaTeX symbol for this.

The trace is defined as the sum on the main diagonal.

Comment: Do you mean `\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}`?

Comment: @AndreyVihrov Yeah. I think I do.

Comment: I dislike defining your own zoo of operators for every standard symbol as it is likely it is not implemented as well as ones in standard packages. Thus I would rather use package like [Physics](https://ctan.org/pkg/physics?lang=en). I would add it as an answer, but the question is mistakenly considered a duplicate due to a bad possible solution.

Answer (score 63):

I prefer the following definition:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}
```

Comment: The `\mathrm` is automatically issued by `\DeclareMathOperator`.

Comment: Whoever down voted this, please provide some info as to what exactly is wrong with this answer. I find it useful to know why things are wrong and not just that they are wrong.