# How to type hyperbolic secant (sech)?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, math-operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Define additional math operators to be typeset in roman](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/671/define-additional-math-operators-to-be-typeset-in-roman)

I'm trying to type the `sech` (Hyperbolic Secant) in LaTeX, but when I do use `\sech(z)`
it will be known as an "Undefined control sequence". So how should I type it in LaTeX?

Comment: The mentioned question shows the solution, so we will close as a duplicate. If you wish, you could edit your question, we could reopen it if desired.