# Is there a command for inverse secant (arcsec)?

Tags: math-mode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Define additional math operators to be typeset in roman](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/671/define-additional-math-operators-to-be-typeset-in-roman)

`\arccos`, `\arcsin`, and `\arctan` seem to work, but not `\arcsec`, `\arccot`, `\arccsc`. I'm using the following math packages: `amsmath`,`amssymb`,`amsthm`.

Comment: these aren't defined in `amsmath`, which is the applicable package.  but they're easily enough cloned from the definition of one of the others as they appear in `amsopn.sty`.  (`amsopn.sty` is loaded automatically by `amsmath`.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can define them yourself, with `\DeclareMathOperator`. See chapter 5 of [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)s manual.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arcsec}{arcsec}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arccot}{arccot}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arccsc}{arccsc}
\begin{document}
\( \arcsec \arccot \arccsc \)
\end{document}
```