# What's the difference between \mathrm and \operatorname?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, math-operators

I apparently can't see the difference in a compilation (pdflatex) between `\mathrm` and `\operatorname`. So, as in the title the question is: is there a difference? Which one is preferable in what occasions?

Comment: "`\mathrm` is used to make variables and units appear in roman (non-italic) text." - You can use it for units for example.

Answer (score 307, accepted):

There are many differences. The main one is in the fact that `\mathrm{xyz}` behaves like an ordinary letter, while `\operatorname{xyz}` behaves like function names such as `\sin`. Here's an illustration

```
$\sin x + \sin(x+y) + a\sin z$

$\mathrm{sin} x + \mathrm{sin}(x+y) + a\mathrm{sin}z$
```

[image]

where it's clear that the second line is typeset wrong. Even if your "operator" requires parentheses after it, it should be `\operatorname`, as the third summand shows, where a thin space separates the coefficient from the operator.

Another subtle difference is in how some characters are interpreted in `\mathrm` and in `\operatorname`. Suppose you have an operator to be called "pre-norm", with a hyphen. Here's the example

```
$\operatorname{pre-norm}(\mathbf{v})$

$\mathrm{pre-norm}(\mathbf{v})$
```

[image]

and now it's clear what is to be used. Indeed `\operatorname` (and the same holds for macros defined with `\DeclareMathOperator`) treats punctuation symbols in a special way; `\mathrm`, instead, treats them as math symbols.

Comment: Can you please tell the full form of the `rm` in `mathrm`? Thank you!

Comment: @GaurangTandon `rm` stands for “roman”, that conventionally denotes the upright type used in the document.

Comment: Wrapping `\mathrm` with `\mathop` addresses the first point (spacing). Replacing `\mathrm` with `\textrm` addresses the second point (characters interpreted as math inside `\mathrm{...}`). So the next question is: what’s the difference between `\mathop{\textrm{...}}` and `\operatorname{...}`?

Comment: @Maëlan Try `$\mathop{\textrm{xyz}}$` inside a theorem statement typeset in italics.

Answer (score 56):

**`\operatorname`:**

The argument is written in upright mode but with some additional
space before and behind.

**`\mathrm`:**

It is like math mode (no spaces), but in upright mode. The font size isn't changed.

The following example shows the differences:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[x\operatorname{foo}y\]
\[x\mathrm{foo}y\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

In other `LaTeX` environments `\mathrm{xyz}` is useful. In `MathJax v 2.0`

```
$ i \\, \mathrm{sinh} \; $
```

gave the equivalent output as `$ i \sinh x $`. `MathJax` did not recognize `\operatorname`.

Comment: \operatorname is now supported with the ASMmath.js TeX extension.

Comment: Typo in the comment by @ChrisR (important if you're searching): it's AMSmath.js, (not ASMmath.js).