# Difference between \mathrm, \operatorname and \text?

Tags: math-mode, formatting, amsmath

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the difference between \mathrm and \operatorname?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48459/whats-the-difference-between-mathrm-and-operatorname)

I am a beginner of latex, and am always having a hard time differentiate these commands since they seem always produce the same result in math mode. So I am wondering what is the difference between them?

Comment: No, they don’t. `\text` picks up the text-font settings outside of the math-mode it is used in. Everything else: [What's the difference between `\mathrm` and `\operatorname`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48459/whats-the-difference-between-mathrm-and-operatorname)

Comment: Besides that, `\mathrm` (and `\text`) do not understand the concept of limits (`\limits`/`\nolimits`). Further Reference: [Is there a preference of when to use `\text` and `\mathrm`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19502/is-there-a-preference-of-when-to-use-text-and-mathrm)

Comment: As suggested by @Qrrbrbirlbel the first sentence of your question isn't correct. Please consider correcting it because it may give the wrong impression to starting users.

Comment: @marc sentencing changed!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: @minimax Looks better.