# Display "standalone multiline equations" side-by-side, with QED at right location

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, vertical-alignment

I am looking for an environment that makes the following align properly:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
  \begin{equation*}
    \frac{\begin{gathered} here \\ are \\ three ~ lines \end{gathered}}{conclusion}
  \end{equation*}
  \begin{equation*}
    \frac{\begin{gathered} here ~ are \\ two ~ lines \end{gathered}}{conclusion}
  \end{equation*}
  \begin{equation*}
    \frac{\begin{gathered} here ~ is ~ one ~ line \end{gathered}}{conclusion}
  \end{equation*}
  \qed
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

That is:

- I have several equations that I want to display side-by-side
- I cannot use `align` or things like that, as I want to maintain each equation as one unit. I thus cannot combine every line with `&`. Furthermore, they do not always consist of line of equal sizes.
- The `\qed` should appear at the height of the longest equation, which can be any position (1 in this case)
- Ideally, I can adjust the alignment of the equations shorter than the longest equation (i.e. switch between top, center, or bottom aligned.

Comment: For the text you can use or `\mathrm` or `\text`: it is better.

Comment: Thans @Sebastiano, the text in the example is just that: an example (my real document contains much more complicated equations). However, is there any difference between `\mathrm` and `\text`?

Comment: For my humble opinion there are very similar. But here there is an answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88794/difference-between-mathrm-operatorname-and-text?noredirect=1&lq=1