# How to insert long subscripts involving characters?

Tags: subscripts

I tried to write METrate (where rate denotes the subscript) as $MET_rate$. But only r appears as subscript.When I tried writing it as $MET_r_a_t_e$ I get it in the correct format during compilation as expected but it throws an error "Double subscript".

Comment: Using braces `{…}` to get all the expression as a subscript probably answer your question. But writing this expression in math mode (i.e., surrounded by `$`) is probably wrong. You should have a look at [this answer on `\textsubscript`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1014/34551) and consider using [`mathrm` or `operatorname`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48459/34551).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put the subscript within curly braces. Replace `$MET_rate$` by `$MET_{rate}$`.

Comment: Better still, write either `$\mathrm{MET}_{\mathrm{rate}}$` or `$\mathit{MET}_{\mathit{rate}}$`, depending on whether the variable names "MET" and "rate" should be rendered in upright or italic form.