# Correctly left align a set of equations

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, equations

I have a set of equations and I want to have them left-aligned instead of center-aligned. Also, I want them all to be numbered. I searched a bit and found that using `flalign` we can achieve this. But the results are not what I want. I want all the equations to start from the left at same position. What am I missing?

Here's the minimal working example showing what I have tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{flalign}
  f_1 = \sigma(W_{1}x_1+W_{2}h_{1}+W_{3}c_{1}+b_1)  \\
  f_2 = \sigma(W_{2}x_2+b_2) \\
  c = f_i c+i\; \mathrm{cos}(W_{3}x_1+W_{3}h_{1}+b_3) \\
  y=c\; \mathrm{tanh}(f_1.f_2) 
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is surely related to the fact that you haven't actually specified an alignment point in your `align` environment. Also you should be using `\cos` for the proper spacing. Same with `\tanh` which, to my surprise, does seem to be provided out of the box. For those which aren't, like artanh, you'll wanna add `\DeclareMathOperator{\artanh}{artanh}` to the preamble and then use `\artanh`

Comment: Do you want all your equations to be left-aligned,  or only specific ones?

Comment: @Bernard all of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under any of the `align`-like environments, each row follows a `r`ight-`&`-`l`eft alignment. As such, the first element in each row will necessarily be `r`ight-aligned, as you observed. If you want a `l`eft-alignment, consider adding "an empty first group" by just prepending each row by `&`.

Here are some options:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X
\begin{flalign}
  & f_1 = \sigma(W_1 x_1 +W_2 h_1 + W_3 c_1 + b_1) \\
  & f_2 = \sigma(W_2 x_2 + b_2) \\
  &   c = f_i c + i \cos(W_3 x_1 + W_3 h_1 + b_3) \\
  &   y = c \tanh(f_1.f_2) 
\end{flalign}
\noindent X\dotfill X
\begin{flalign}
  f_1 &= \sigma(W_1 x_1 +W_2 h_1 + W_3 c_1 + b_1) \\
  f_2 &= \sigma(W_2 x_2 + b_2) \\
    c &= f_i c + i \cos(W_3 x_1 + W_3 h_1 + b_3) \\
    y &= c \tanh(f_1.f_2) 
\end{flalign}
\noindent X\dotfill X

\end{document}
```

You might be interested in the first representation. I prefer the second.

Note that there already exist operators for the math function you write in `r`o`m`an font: `\cos` and `\tanh`. If you wish to define additional ones (and therefore provide the appropriate spacing) use `\operatorname` and/or `\DeclareMathOperator{<macro>}{<name>}`. See [What's the difference between `\mathrm` and `\operatorname`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48459/5764) and [Define additional math operators to be typeset in roman](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/671/5764).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the helpful explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Note the default for the `[fleqn]` option of amsmath uses a  display indent (~ 2.5em?). The `flalign` environment, independently of the option, displays equations full line width and thus aligns them with the left margin.

Here are a few examples of the different possible situations:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}%
 \usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}%
 \usepackage{nccmath}

 \begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
  f_1 & = \sigma(W_{1}x_1+W_{2}h_{1}+W_{3}c_{1}+b_1 & \\
  f_2 & = \sigma(W_{2}x_2+b_2) \\
  c & = f_i c+i\; \cos(W_{3}x_1+W_{3}h_{1}+b_3) \\
  y & =c\; \tanh(f_1.f_2)
\end{flalign}
\bigskip

\begin{flalign}
 & \begin{gathered}
  f_1  = \sigma(W_{1}x_1+W_{2}h_{1}+W_{3}c_{1}+b_1  \\
  f_2  = \sigma(W_{2}x_2+b_2) \\
  c  = f_i c+i\; \cos(W_{3}x_1+W_{3}h_{1}+b_3) \\
  y  =c\; \tanh(f_1.f_2)
  \end{gathered} &
\end{flalign}
\bigskip

  \begin{align}
 f_1 & = \sigma(W_{1}x_1+W_{2}h_{1}+W_{3}c_{1}+b_1  \\
   f_2 & = \sigma(W_{2}x_2+b_2) \\
  c & = f_i c+i\; \cos(W_{3}x_1+W_{3}h_{1}+b_3) \\
  y & =c\; \tanh (f_1.f_2)
  \end{align}
\bigskip

 \begin{align} &  \begin{gathered}
 f_1  = \sigma(W_{1}x_1+W_{2}h_{1}+W_{3}c_{1}+b_1  \\
   f_2  = \sigma(W_{2}x_2+b_2) \\
  c  = f_i c+i\; \cos(W_{3}x_1+W_{3}h_{1}+b_3) \\
  y  =c\; \tanh (f_1.f_2)
  \end{gathered}
  \end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]