# Error using equation*

Tags: equations

I get an error in the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,english]{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\left\{\begin{matrix}
u_t+vu_x=0 & x \in \mathbb{R}\\ 
g(x)=u(x,0)=\textrm{exp}(-10x^2) & x \in \mathbb{R}
\end{matrix}\right
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

I get the error

```
 Blockquote Missing delimiter (. inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   $
l.12 \end{equation*}                  
I was expecting to see something like `(' or `\{' or
`\}' here. If you typed, e.g., `{' instead of `\{', you
should probably delete the `{' by typing `1' now, so that
braces don't get unbalanced. Otherwise just proceed.
Acceptable delimiters are characters whose \delcode is
nonnegative, or you can use `\delimiter <delimiter code>'.
```

What's the problem? I don't see why it complains for the `\end{equation*}`.

Comment: You need `\right.` here -- note the `.` there, in order to delimite the `\left...\right` construct. The `\left\{` is ok, but since there is no right brace etc, you have to input a dummy delimiter, which is done with `\right.` here... and your example misses `amssymb` package

Comment: `\right.` But why not using `cases`?

Comment: @NobelPrize: No problem... I believe the usual suspects will answer it anyway ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is solved using `\right.` (where `.` denotes the “empty delimiter”). But you should use `cases`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\left\{\begin{matrix}
u_t+vu_x=0 & x \in \mathbb{R}\\
g(x)=u(x,0)=\textrm{exp}(-10x^2) & x \in \mathbb{R}
\end{matrix}\right.
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
u_t+vu_x=0               & x \in \mathbb{R}\\
g(x)=u(x,0)=\exp(-10x^2) & x \in \mathbb{R}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Also it's not `\textrm{exp}`, but `\exp` (which is predefined). See [What's the difference between \mathrm and \operatorname?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48459/whats-the-difference-between-mathrm-and-operatorname) for more information why.

[image]