# How to properly typeset E_{\mathrm{k}} in beamer

Tags: beamer, fonts

Scientific typography makes an important distinction between italic type and roman (upright) type ([exemplary source](http://iupap.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/A4.pdf#page=10)).

The symbol for kinetisch energy is E_k with E printed in italic type, k printed in roman type.

Normally, I would write that as `E_{\mathrm{k}}`.

However, that does not work with `beamer`. The package changes normal math to a sans-serif font, but leaves `\mathrm` a serif-font. The subscript k will be typeset in a serif-font, but it should simply match the default math font, just being upright.

So how do I get the intended behavior in beamer?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  $E_{\mathrm{k}}$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

(Other packages that switch to sans-serif math fonts also redefine `mathrm` to be sans-serif and, of course, upright, e.g. cmbright, sfmath and arevmath.)

Comment: Define intended behavior. I'd probably just use mathbf or redefine mathrm to it. Btw probably should not promote users to use the subscript without the outer braces. It is mostly luck that it works here, better to get new users to always use the braces then they don't get confused when not using braces does not work

Comment: @daleif I added the braces. Intended behavior = The subscript "should simply match the default math font, just being upright". mathbf = bold?

Comment: My bad should have written mathsf. As was mentioned in the comments to another question, it's probably best to use a user defined macro and not hardcode mathrm or similar. Then it is easier to prepare for, for example, beamers oddities

Answer (score 5):

By adding `\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}`, we find the serif font in mathematical formulas.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  $E_\mathrm{k}$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output: [image: energie-cinetique]

Answer (score 4):

One could use `$E_{\mathsf{k}}$`, but that is not very portable.

From the beamer manual:

> Note: The command `\mathrm` will always produce upright (not slanted), serif text and the command
>   `\mathsf` will always produce upright, sans-serif text. The command `\mathbf` will produce upright, boldface,
>   sans-serif or serif text, depending on whether `mathsans` or `mathserif` is used.
>   To produce an upright, sans-serif or serif text, depending on whether `mathsans` or `mathserif` is used, you
>   can use for instance the command `\operatorname` from the `amsmath` package. Using this command instead
>   of \mathrm or \mathsf directly will automatically adjust upright mathematical text if you switch from
>   sans-serif to serif or back.

So, **the beamer way** to do things is to **define an operator** and then use it. But an operator is [not quite the same thing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48463).

In my humble opinion, the `beamer` package is flawed in that respect.

Comment: Probably left over from the fact thst so many users do not mark their operators correctly (I see a lot of people using `\text`), it definitely do not apply here. Not sure if pinging works here, @JosephWright shouldn't theæis phrase in the beamer manual be changed?

Answer (score 3):

Imho the problem is that at the time the names for the math alphabets were choosen sans serif math wasn't really on the agenda of math typesetters. And while I do understand why you want \mathrm to give a sans serif upright font, I would find it a bit curious if *rm* leads to a *sf* font (and that with e.g. arevmath `\mathsf` gives a slanted sf font).

So with pdflatex I would use (this assumes that amsmath is loaded) `\operatorfont`:

```
\documentclass{beamer} %or article
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ifluatex}
\ifluatex
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}
\else
\def\symup{\mathrm}
\fi
\begin{document}
sin

$\sin{x}\quad{\operatorfont sin}{x}\quad\symup{sin}{x}\quad\mathrm{sin}{x}$
\end{document}
```

### output with beamer + pdflatex

[image]

### output with article + pdflatex

[image]

With unicode math I would probably prefer `\symup` (I don't quite understand why unicode-math uses a text font for the operators instead of the math font):

### output with beamer and lualatex

[image]

### output with article and lualatex:

[image]

Comment: So, basically, you say that I should do my own font setup (supporting my notion that beamer's setup is a little bit awkward). // I don't understand your 2nd sentence. Why do you have the notion that *rm* should have serifs? For me, *rm* stands for *roman* = upright letters of the latin script. [IUPAP](http://iupap.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/A4.pdf#page=10) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_type) support my notion. cmbright, sfmath and arevmath see it the same way.

Comment: Well in latex \rmfamily is normally a serif font (you can find quite lot quotes like "\rmfamily selects a roman (i.e., serifed) font family") and \sffamily is a sans serif font. But things are getting fuzzy here too as more and more document use sans serif as main font (and fontspec quite rightly uses now `\setmainfont`).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer aren't we just missing a `\mathup`, aka switch to upright in the current math font.

Comment: @daleif With unicode-math the `\mathXX` switch to textfonts and so are never "in the current math font". There you should use imho `\symup`.  With pdflatex  a \mathup using the operator font could make sense.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer since I hardly ever use the unicode setup (too unstable and confusing interface) accessing the operator font could be ok, but at other times one might want the upright text font (say, you're typesetting an index on a variable and it contains non-ascii letters)

Comment: @daleif in classical latex the operatorfont is identical to mathrm, both refer to OT1/cmr, see fontmath.ltx. If you want non-ascii-letters you should better escape to the real text font with something like `\text{\normalfont ...}`.

Comment: But unfortunately, the spacing between `\sin` and `x` is only correct, when using `$\sin {x}`.  Everything else may use the correct font, but the incorrect spacing :-(  Frustrating, as I have the same problem over here.

Comment: @Jan you get the correct spacing with \mathop, but this wasn't the question here.