# Further questions about mathrm and operatorname: spacing after \colon

Tags: math-operators

**EDIT: As clarified in the answers below, this appears to be a bug with `amsmath` and `colon` and thus doesn't really have anything to do with `mathrm` versus `operatorname`.**

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48459/whats-the-difference-between-mathrm-and-operatorname) question contains an enlightening discussion between using `\mathrm` and `\operatorname`. The tl;dr version is: whenever you have an *operator*, use `\operatorname`.

However it seems bad to use `\operatorname` if what you are defining is a *set*, since in general `\operatorname` adds a little space before it. This means that an expression like:

```
f \colon \operatorname{End}(V) \to \mathbb{R}
```

renders badly, as there is too much white space between the colon and the `operatorname{End}`. Using `\mathrm` (the RHS) is more visually appealing:
[image: operatorname vs mathrm]

Thus if one views `\operatorname{End}(V)` as a *set*, then it makes more sense to write `\mathrm{End}(V)`.

Now one can view `\operatorname{End}` also a *functor* on the category of vector spaces, for instance, then you would want the `\operatorname`:
[image: End as a functor]

**My question is this:** What is the best practice when dealing with a quantity that is used both as a set and an operator? Should one really switch between `\mathrm` and `\operatorname` as appropriate? Or is there a better option.

Comment: IMHO, this looks like a bug in the (re)definition of `\colon` made by the `amsmath` package.  **Edit:** Oh, by the way, *welcome to TeX.SX!* (:-)

Comment: Please say exactly which packages you are using.  With just `amsopn` there is no difference in the output

Comment: See https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/91 for discussion of the bug.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's a very interesting observation.

The definition of `\colon` in `amsmath` is

```
\renewcommand{\colon}{
  \nobreak
  \mskip 2mu
  \mathpunct{}
  \nonscript
  \mkern-\thinmuskip
  {:}
  \mskip 6mu plus 1mu\relax
}
```

(edited to show the various parts). The space you see is a consequence of the fact that `\colon` ends with an ordinary atom, namely `{:}`.

It would have been better to use `\mathopen`, as the following test shows. I first get an alias of `\colon` and patch it to change `{:}` into `\mathopen:`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\let\pcolon\colon
\patchcmd{\pcolon}{{:}}{\mathopen:}{}{}

\begin{document}

$f \colon \operatorname{End}(V) \to R$

$f \pcolon \operatorname{End}(V) \to R$

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{@{}*{8}{l}@{}}
&0&1&2&3&4&5&6 \\
\verb|\colon| &
  $\colon A$ &
  $\colon \max$ &
  $\colon +$ &
  $\colon \sim$ &
  $\colon ($ &
  $\colon )$ &
  $\colon ,$
\\
\verb|\pcolon| &
  $\pcolon A$ &
  $\pcolon \max$ &
  $\pcolon +$ &
  $\pcolon \sim$ &
  $\pcolon ($ &
  $\pcolon )$ &
  $\pcolon ,$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

In the tests, `\colon` is followed by a symbol in each class.

[image]

The only noticeable differences are in the cases when `\colon` is followed by atoms of class 1 (operators) and 3 (relations), performing perhaps better in both.

If you want to follow this suggestion, your document can load `etoolbox` and do

```
\patchcmd{\colon}{{:}}{\mathopen:}{}{}
```

I don't think that it's possible to fix `amsmath` as many existing documents depend on it and such a change would affect the output and line breaks. It might be possible to add an option for using a fixed definition.

Comment: Exactly what I [meant](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461537/further-questions-about-mathrm-and-operatorname#comment1160670_461537)! (+1)  But why not replace `:` with `\mathpunct:` and compensate for the excess space in the final `\mskip`?

Comment: @GuM That could be another idea. I wanted to do minimal changes.

Comment: @GuM The original definition has `\mathpunct{}\nonscript-\thinmuskip`, which adds `\thinmuskip` in scriptstyle/scriptscriptstyle. Using `\mathpunct:` would need more computations.

Comment: Forget about my comment: looking at the table on p. 170, a Punct atom is always followed by “(1)” glue; so, using `\mathpunct:\nonscript\mskip-\thinmuskip` as the replacement code, which is what I was suggesting, amounts to having “(0)” glue after the colon, irrespective of the kind of atom that follows; which is precisely what `\mathopen:` does! (:-)

Comment: any ideas on whether we should do that (and option names if we do)? perhaps best as a gh issue so any change can point to that discussion/

Comment: Oh wow, that is interesting! Thank you very much for the insight!

Comment: There are other examples where the spacing doesn't work using `\operatorname`, but I guess for less interesting reasons. For instance, if one uses `\operatorname{Diff}(M)` for the group of diffeomorphisms then either of the common notations `T_f \operatorname{Diff}(M)` (for the tangent space at `f`) and `\operatorname{Diff}_f M` give spacing errors which aren't present if one used `\mathrm` instead.

Comment: @Howard You *want* a thin space before an operatorname in that case, in my opinion.