# Upright matematical letters in every environment

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

I apologize in advance if this question has already been asked, and if it is a dumb question: my knowledge of LaTeX is very limited.

I'm doing a thesis in mathematics, and I've some problems regarding formulas, which sometimes appear upright -like using `\text{}`-, sometimes in italic -like using `\emph{}`-.

I divided the claims in two groups: `\theoremstyle{plain}` -for theorems, propositions, etc- and `\theoremstyle{definition}` -for definitions, remarks-.

Now, I use many times the letter `$\text{H}$` to denote the cohomology: I therefore defined a new command

```
\newcommand{\coh}{\emph{H}}
```

but unfortunately, when is used in a definition, it is in italic, while in a theorem environment it is straight: how can I impose to LaTeX to always print this letter upright, no matter the environment in which is used? I tried `\newcommand{\coh}{\text{H}}` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). Include the package `\usepackage{mathtools}` (which includes `amsmath`) and then using `\DeclareMathOperator{\coh}{H}` should give you the desired results.  FYI, instead of descrbing the problem, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: @PeterGrill as of my knowledge `\DeclareMathOperator` is one of the best solution, can you make this as `answer` for this topic? So that it will help all to find solution in future...

Comment: Thanks a lot @PeterGrill: I apologize for how I have written my question, it was my very first post on TSE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `\DeclareMathOperator{\coh}{H}` which yields the same results in normal usage and in italics:

[image]

#### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\coh}{H}

\begin{document}
In normal usage we have an upright $\coh$.

In emphasized text it appears the same \emph{$\coh$}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Correct for this particular case (the cohomology operator), but `\DeclareMathOperator` is not a general purpose command for defining “always upright letters”, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48459/4427

Answer (score 4):

You can use `\textnormal{H}`, to reset the formatting.  The `\text` command inherits the formatting the surrounding text.  That is, because a theorem statement is italicized, the italics will bleed through into math formulas.  So would bold or sans-serif or small-caps formatting if you use `$\text{H}$` in a header.

You can instead use `\mathrm{H}`, which is always upright, and spaced like an ordinary math symbol.  If you use `\DeclareMathOperator`, you will get spacing like log or sin.

The `unicode-math` package gives you the choice between `\mathrm` (which uses the text font, but can be changed) and `\symup` (which uses the math font, but can be changed).  This allows you to use distinct fonts for ordinary words in math mode, and for upright math symbols.  (You might try upright italics, or Neo Euler.)

If you want to inherit the weight but reset the shape (so that a formula in a bold header is bold), you can use `\textup{H}`.  Alternatively, `\text{\rmfamily\upshape H}` lets you set font axes individually.

It would be a good idea to define commands like this once, in the preamble.

Comment: It is very very rare you'd ever want to use `\text`, for one of course it switches to the text font, which depending on setup my be different from the upright font used in math. I'm only mentioning this as we see so many users misuse `\text`  because they think it gives them upright text. Which as you rightfully mention it does not always do. Though I rend to think that many users does not know what "inherits formatting from the surrounding text" actually mean.

Comment: @daleif OK, I added a bit of explanation.

Comment: You actually did much better than most. Often the fact that it switches is not even mentioned.