# Writing GL(V) in standard math form

Tags: math-mode

To write GL(V), I am facing the following problem:

If we put it in dollar signs, then G and L will look in italic form;

To avoid this, I write `\mbox{GL}(V)`. This produces G and L in standard form appearing in texts and papers.

But, if I am writing a statement in italic, and if I write `\mbox{GL}(V)` for GL, then again, G and L will look italic.

**Question:** What is correct way to write GL(V) in standard math form, which will remain same even after its inclusion in italic statement or standard statement?

Answer (score 3):

I'd use `amsmath`'s `\DeclareMathOperator`

```latex
\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}
```

and then write `\GL(V)` in math mode.

(The result is the same as using `\operatorname{GL}(V)` but more convenient.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd simply use `\mathrm`:

```
$\mathrm{GL}(V)$
```

See also [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48459/whats-the-difference-between-mathrm-and-operatorname).