# How to write maths without italics

Tags: math-mode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Define additional math operators to be typeset in roman](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/671/define-additional-math-operators-to-be-typeset-in-roman)

easy question. I am writing some maths and I want to write the epigraph of a function so I type `$epi(\varphi)$` but the `epi` comes out in italics. I want it to come out as `$\log(x)$` would  except obviously I cannot use `$\epi$`. How do I do it?

Comment: We've closed this as a duplicate to make it easier for others looking for how to do this to find the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do:

```
\newcommand{\epi}{\operatorname{epi}}
```

then `\epi` will work just as `\log` does. I believe `amsmath` also provides:

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\epi}{epi}
```

which does the same thing.

Comment: and use `\DeclareMathOperator*{\epi}{epi}` if you want it to place limits above and below in displayed math.