# How to type error function in LaTeX math environment

Tags: math-mode, symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Define additional math operators to be typeset in roman](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/671/define-additional-math-operators-to-be-typeset-in-roman)

It may be a very simple question to people who know.

If I want to type commonly used functions like exponential function exp(x) or sinusoidal function sin(x), I use `\exp(x)` and `\sin(x)` in LaTeX and the results looks nice (fonts become different from other non-function characters). However, when I type error function `\erf(x)`, it gives me error messages. If I remove `\`, it compiles fine but the "erf(x)" fonts just look the same to other non-function characters. Could anyone please tell me how to make the error function fonts look like as exponential function in a math environment? Thanks very much.

Comment: Please take a look at the question I've just linked to.  If it answers your question we'll close this as a duplicate of it to help others find the answer quickly.  If not, please explain what doesn't work so people can best know how to help you.

Answer (score 27):

```
\DeclareMathOperator\erf{erf}
```

not every command imaginable are defined by default (assumes `amsmath` of course)