# How should I write arctanh?

Tags: math-mode, best-practices

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Define additional math operators to be typeset in roman](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/671/define-additional-math-operators-to-be-typeset-in-roman)

If I want to use the function sin in LaTeX, I write `$\sin x$` or `$\sin(x+1)$`. If I want to use the function arctanh, I can't use `$\arctanh x$`:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...\ (\cos x)' &= -\sin x \\ (\arctanh 
                                                  x)' &= \frac {1}{\sqrt {1 ...
l.74 \end{align*}

? 
! Emergency stop.
```

**What should I use instead for arctanh?**

I thought of `$\text{arctanh} x$`, but this doesn't leave a space after arctanh. Additionally, it seems to be semantically incorrect, as arctanh is not "only" text.

Comment: You could also use `\atanh{x}` of the `physymb` package. It gives tanh^-1.

Comment: arctanh is semantically wrong. The right word is artanh, where "ar" is the abbreviation for area and not for arc.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`\text` is not well suited for this, use

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator\arctanh{arctanh}
```

then `\arctanh` behaves like `\tan` and friends

Comment: typo: MathOperator not MahOperator