# Binary Logarithm Function

Tags: math-mode, macros

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Define additional math operators to be typeset in roman](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/671/define-additional-math-operators-to-be-typeset-in-roman)

Math mode provides different functions to use in formulas like `\sin`, `\cos`, `\tan` or `\log`.

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_logarithm), the alternative form of the binary logarithm *log2(n)* is either written *ld(n)* (common practice) or *lb(n)* (ISO standard).

LaTeX provides a function `\log` and `\lg`, but no `\ld` or `\lb`. Is this on purpose? Am I missing some package? Or can I achieve the same look (I assume it's just non-cursive text) by creating some custom functions/macros?

Comment: @egreg you're right, in that case I guess this can be closed :) thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. We are waiting for other contributions from you: questions and, possibly, answers. `:-)`

Comment: +1 for knowing which SE site is the right one for LaTeX questions ;)

Comment: @tohecz I've been following this site and its newsletter quite a while, great stuff :)