# Is there a command of the type "\blabla" where I can write \mbox{div}(F)

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

Maybe my question is easy. When I want to write

```
$$ \mbox{div}(F) = \sum_i (F_i)_{x_i} $$
```

I have to type `\mbox{div}(F)`, which is cumbersome.

Is there a way to define a command `\blabla` to produce `\mbox{div}(F)`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/671/define-additional-math-operators-to-be-typeset-in-roman help? If it does, then we can close this question as duplicate; otherwise, please add to your question some more details.

Comment: @egreg: I'm pretty sure the use of `$$` stems from Math.SE, as the user is register there.

Comment: If the question is about MathJax, I don't think there's much to do about it.

Comment: For a drop-in replacement of that command sequence you can simply wirte `\newcommand{\blabla}{\mbox{div}(F)}` and thereafter use `\blabla`.  However, do have a look at the question pointed to by @egreg.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you want

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\mydiv}{div}
```

in your preamble. Then you could write

```
\begin{equation}
\mydiv(F) = ...
\end{equation}
```

Please don't use the outdated `$$` for displayed equations as detailed in [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to).