# Why do math operators not behave like normal control sequences?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, math-operators

From my experience, most control sequences function as an implicit group, for example 
`g^\textrm{th}`. However, if we look at the example below, the first line throws an error while the second line does not.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$g^\mod$
$g^{\mod}$

\end{document}
```

I first noticed this because I used `DeclareMathOperator` to declare my own operators, based on the answer to [Define additional math operators to be typeset in roman](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/671/define-additional-math-operators-to-be-typeset-in-roman).

I then tried with `\mod` which is defined in `amsmath`

What is the reason that math operators do not play well with `^`, unlike other control sequences, and is there an option to make them do so without explicit `{}`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually, most control sequences do *not* function as an implicit group; you have simply been lucky with your choice of superscripts.  `\textrm` is a *font* macro, and has been carefully designed as such to work without braces in a superscript for just this purpose.  If you were to define your own macro

```
\newcommand*\timestwo[1]{2*#1}
```

you would find that `$g^\timestwo{x}$` would be accepted, but produce the equivalent of `${g^2} * 2$`.  This is because TeX will expand "arguments" to an exponent `^` but then take the first group (more or less) for the actual text of the exponent.  (Hence, `\textrm` works by expanding in such a way as to make a group around its argument the first thing that `^` eventually sees.)

Something similar happens with `\mod`, which in fact expects an argument: writing `\show\mod` at the command line would say

```
\mod=\long macro:
#1->\allowbreak \if@display \mkern 18mu \else \mkern 12mu\fi {\operator@font mod}\,\,#1.
```

That is, you're *supposed* to use it as `\mod n`.  In fact, this one will give you an additional error because the first typesettable material seen by `^` is the `\mkern`, and since it's not expandable it both a) does *not* absorb its "argument" (either `18mu` or `12mu` depending on context) and b) is taken on its own as an exponent.  And the expression `\mkern` without an argument is invalid.

If you just want the upright-typeset operator called "mod", you can `\DeclareMathOperator{\Mod}{mod}` and *that* will be usable in a superscript, because it is a single token taking no arguments.