# Avoiding italicization in math mode

Tags: math-mode, italic

I want to avoid text being italicized when it's inside dollar signs. For example I want the Gal part of `$Gal(f)$` to show as plain text, without having to write `Gal$(f)$`. How do I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: In the present form, LaTeX does not know that it corresponds to a specific math notation, you have to tell it that the letters go together and they should not be italicized as usual variables. You can try adding `\DeclareMathOperator{\Gal}{Gal}` in the preamble, which should do just that (and then `$\Gal(f)$` in the body of the text).

Comment: This question seems very similar in generic solution to [Define additional math operators to be typeset in roman](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/671/5764)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `${\rm Gal}(f)$` or `$\mathrm{Gal}(f)$`.

Comment: I would recommend against this in favor of `DeclareMathOperator` (as mentioned in the comments). This answer is *the* way to do it in the general, for things such as `if` notes in the definitions of continuous functions, say, but isn't terribly suited for this particular case, where `Gal` is in fact a math operator which requires some care in spacing.

Comment: You should not recommend that people use `{\rm}`, as it has been deprecated for the last twenty years.

Answer (score 1):

I've declared a new command in my style file:

```
\newcommand{\x}[1]{\text{#1}}
```

and then, whenever I want plain text inside a math environment, I just do `\x{text here}`. I do this so often, it's definitely worth the new command.

Comment: `\text` used in this way will follow the style of the surrounding text.  so if you're in an italicized theorem, what's inside `\x{...}` will also be italic.  better to use `\textrm{...}`.  (assumes you are using `amsmath` and its definition of `\text`.)