# Preventing Ångström symbol being italicised in pythontex

Tags: fonts, math-mode, symbols, python

I'm trying to make a plot in a tex document within pythontex and I set the label within pycode tags to be

```
self.label = r'A: {0} B: {1:.0f}$\AA$'.format(self.aaa,self.bbb)
```

I don't want the Ångström symbol to be in italics, but I don't see how to prevent it. The various suggested methods here don't seem to work inside pythontex, and I don't know how to apply "[Define additional math operators to be typeset in roman](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/671/define-additional-math-operators-to-be-typeset-in-roman)" to my situation.

Any guidance would be appreciated!
Thank you.

Comment: How about removing the `$`, or `$\textrm{\AA}$`?

Comment: Right! `textrm` gies me `KeyError: '\\AA'` but simply removing the `$`-signs gives me the Å-symbol without italics. I must have missed guessing that in the long list of things I tried. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\AA` should be used as-is in text-mode. Dropping the math-mode characters should solve your problems.