# Why are certain mathematics operators not defined and how do I replicate them?

Tags: math-mode, best-practices, math-operators

I noticed that while `\ker` renders correctly as the "kernel" operator in Linear Algebra, the corresponding `\im` for the "image" is not defined (I tried everything that could possibly be an abbreviation for "image") nor is "rank" given a command.

Can I get these operators from some kind of 'math add-on' package? And if not, how should I typeset operators correctly? I tried `\text{im}A` but this didn't put any space, so I ended up doing `\text{im}\, A` - is that the right amount of spacing for an operator?

EDIT: Also, what's the difference between `\text{stuff}` and `\mathrm{text}`?

Comment: Use `\DeclareMathOperator{}{}` with the `amsmath` package.

Comment: What do I put in the two braces?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/671/86 for the main part of the question.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `\DeclareMathOperator` to declare other math operators:

[image]

There are way too many to have them all defined so `\DeclareMathOperator` is provided to allow one to define their own.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{im}

\begin{document}
\[
\ker A \quad \im B
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok so the first brace is the code, and the second is what it will write? So I could do a shortcut like \DeclareMathOperator{\i}{image} and have it write out "image" is that correct?

Comment: Can I make a package with a bunch of those "declare operators" that I can use in all my papers?

Comment: I'd recommend using longer names over shorter names so as to not overwrite any existing macros. Even if you check that a particular macro names is not currently in use, it may be used by a package that you decide to use in the future. So `\Image` would be preferable over `\i` (which already has a meaning). And yes you can put all these in one `.sty` file and just include it as you do other packages.

Comment: Ok got it, cheers!