# How to define this operator der Omega(A)?

Tags: symbols, math-operators

I need to define a command to create a notation like

[image]

because I don't want to write

[image]

However, the spacing in the first image is not cool. I'd like it to be like the space between tan and theta here:

[image]

How can I do that?
Thanks.

Comment: How do you write that? Please show some LaTeX code (MWE).

Comment: It's as easy as this: `\DeclareMathOperator{\der}{der}` in your preamble.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Define additional math operators to be typeset in roman](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/671/5764)

Comment: @Bernard really cool, that was exactly I was looking for. Thanks =)

Comment: @TeXnician I had written as \mathsf{der}(\Omega(A))..

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to fell helpful. Note that if you want `der` to be typed with default sans family, just incorporate it in the declaration, with `\DeclareMathOperator{\der}{\textsf{der}}`.

Comment: Right, I'll try =)