# Big Brackets not working

Tags: math-mode, delimiters

I'm not sure why, but

`$$Cov(X,Y) = E\left((X-\mu_X)(Y-\mu_Y)\right)$$`

doesn't seem to give me big brackets.

Comment: These brackets are not necessarily big, it depends on the size of what they enclose. Use e.g. `\[Cov(X,Y) = E\bigl((X-\mu_X)(Y-\mu_Y)\bigr)\]` to get bigger brackets. Or `\[\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y) = E\bigl((X-\mu_X)(Y-\mu_Y)\bigr)\]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @user240002 pointed out in a comment, "big" delimiters aren't necessarily big: they merely scale to match their content. If the content doesn't have a lot of height (or depth), they won't scale.

You can override the default sizes using `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg` and `\Bigg`; for left and right delimiters it's best to use `\bigl` and `\bigr` (entirely analogous variants exist for the rest of the bunch, and if you happen to need something in the middle there's also `\bigm`).

The downside is that the size won't automatically adjust anymore, of course. So instead, you can also force brackets to be larger: add a `\strut` to force a certain minimum height/depth, or use a `\vphantom{...}`. I recommend experimenting here, not just to solve the immediate problem but also to learn a new trick or two that'll surely come in handy in the future.

A few other tips:

- It's recommended that instead of `$$ ... $$`, you use `\[ ... \]` in LaTeX; see [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to)  (that, or use a named environment like `equation`).
- `statmath` is a useful package that has shortcut commands for a number of things you'll need for statistics, including `\cov` and `\E`.
- If you want to roll your own (e.g. because you prefer an uppercase `\Cov`), it's recommended to use `\DeclareMathOperator` from `amsmath`; see [Define additional math operators to be typeset in roman](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/671/define-additional-math-operators-to-be-typeset-in-roman) .
- If you want to use italics there, or otherwise need them for multi-letter variable names, use `\mathit`, i.e. `\mathit{Cov}` instead of `Cov`; that'll give you better spacing.

That's all I have.

Comment: Thanks very much for your tips.

Comment: @Martin you're welcome! BTW, if this answer helped you, it'd be nice if you could accept it by clicking on the checkmark symbol.