# How to make the subscript of a \DeclareMathOperator* used in an equation seem like the one used in inline math?

Tags: amsmath

I have a symbol defined by `DeclareMathOperator*`:

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\Symb}{Symb}
```

When I add a subscript to it in the inline-math mode, i.e., `$\Symb_{\mathbftt{AB}}$`, it is displayed as expected:

[image]

But if I use it in an `equation`, the subscript is rendered like a limit right underneath the symbol:

[image]

How can I make the second usage look like the first one?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 

\newcommand\mathbftt[1]{\textnormal{\ttfamily\bfseries #1}}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\Symb}{Symb}

\begin{document} 
 $\Symb_{\mathbftt{AB}}$
 \begin{equation}
    \Symb_{\mathbftt{AB}}
 \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\textstyle`. But then I wonder why you use `\DeclareMathOperator`

Comment: @Denis: Right, thanks.

Comment: @Denis `\DeclareMathOperator ` would not have the unwanted effect, the OP used `\DeclareMathOperator*`

Comment: note there is no bold tt in cm so in this case you could simply use `\mathtt` although if your real document uses other fonts the situation might be different

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/671/4427

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

The `*` form you used is to request that behaviour of subscripts, so simply delete the `*`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 

\newcommand\mathbftt[1]{\textnormal{\ttfamily\bfseries #1}}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Symb}{Symb}

\begin{document} 
 $\Symb_{\mathbftt{AB}}$
 \begin{equation}
    \Symb_{\mathbftt{AB}}
 \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I overlooked the unstarred version. Thanks.